# path contains non-directory or non-existent components: /path/to/project?

Tags: macos, nfs

I'm trying to export a directory for NFS on MacOS, but am running into this error:

```
exports:3: path contains non-directory or non-existent components: /path/to/project
```

The path is coming from `$PWD` and I verified that the path exists. How to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NFS doesn't seem to like symbolic links. When I changed to path to an absolute path it worked.